# Making sense of blocks python package output

Tags: python, neural-network, accuracy

I've modified the `Blocks` [tutorial](http://blocks.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html), to train an MLP neural net with a dataset provided for an assignment in my ML course.

I'd like to evaluate the accuracy of the network with varying parameterization, but I am not sure how to obtain the accuracy in first place.

Inspecting the `main_loop` object useing `dir()` & `vars()`, I'm not coming across anything other than `the test_cost_with_regularization`.

It is possible to record means of different `Theano` variables via the monitor classes, so perhaps the answer lies there within?

**Final Output**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
TRAINING HAS BEEN FINISHED:
---------------------------------------------------------
Training status:
     batch_interrupt_received: False
     epoch_interrupt_received: False
     epoch_started: False
     epochs_done: 1
     iterations_done: 16
     received_first_batch: True
     resumed_from: None
     training_started: True
Log records from the iteration 16:
     test_cost_with_regularization: 2.3032071347
     training_finish_requested: True
     training_finished: True
```